# Issue in simple authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication

I created a login page. I am trying to authenticate a user by sending the message from the backend after verifying if the user exists in the database.
Everything is working fine just one problem is that when I login with correct credentials I have to click twice on the submit button for it to work.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
const Login = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState("Wrong");
  const [mssg, setMssg] = useState("");
  const handleUser = (e) => {
    setUsername(e.target.value);
  };
  const handlePassword = (e) => {
    setPassword(e.target.value);
  };
  const login = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const user = { username, password };
    console.log(user);
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/auth", user)
      .then((res) => setAuth(res.data.message))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    if (auth === "OK") {
      sessionStorage.setItem("user", username);
      window.location = "/dashboard";
    } else {
      setMssg("Invalid Details. Please try again");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={login}>
        <input onChange={handleUser}></input>
        <input type="password" onChange={handlePassword}></input>
        <input type="submit"></input>
      </form>
      <p id="mssg">{mssg}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

When i login with correct credentials, it throws the error. But when i submit again with the same correct credentials, then it redirects me to the dashboard.

Comment: can you also share with us the error you get?

Comment: You dont understand. I dont get any errors. I throw the error when user enters invalid credenials.

Comment: I posted an answer using `useEffect` to redirect once logged in successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can here make usage of the [useEffect](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook that would help you redirect:

```js
useEffect(()=>{
if (auth === "OK") {
    sessionStorage.setItem("user", username);
    window.location = "/dashboard";
} else {
    setMssg("Invalid Details. Please try again");
}
}, [auth])
```

here you can see we're passing the auth state as dependencies that would make useEffect call the function we're passing each time auth changes that would allow us to redirect the user whenever he's logged in!
PS: Do not forget to remove the section of code I used inside `useEffect` from your login function

Comment: I dont think that works. It sets the error message to the "Invalid" before i even submit the credentials